# iOS: How to select and scroll to a specific cell in a collectionView in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to select and scroll to a specific `indexPath` in a `collectionView` with centring it. I found that functions, but impossible to combine them:

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredVertically)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass options set `[.centeredHorizontally,.centeredVertically]`

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.centeredHorizontally,.centeredVertically], animated: true)
```